# Updating the first occurrence of the column with a value and the remaining with other value

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

```
select emp_id, emp_dept, emp_name
from employee
where emp_id in (123, 234);


emp_id  emp_dept    emp_name
*****************************
123     222         1234
123     222         5678
123     222         9101
234     222         1011
234     222         1112
234     222         1213
```

Here there are 3 records for each emp_id.
I want a query to update the emp_dept such that out of three records, only one record will be updated to 555(it can be any record doesnt matter) and the other 2 will be updated to 666.

Comment: Can you reformat this and show what you've tried?

Comment: which database? sql-server?

Comment: emp_name or emp_ssn?

Comment: does the direction I wrote work for you?  I know oracle has cte and window functions but I am not always up to date on what is sql-server specific syntax rather than ANSI so I made my code pretty standard.  Anyway I am pretty confident the method should work for you.let me know.

Comment: the select part worked but i am unable to update it. It shows 'missing select statement error'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MERGE](http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html).

**Data Preparation**

```
create table em1(
emp_id number, emp_dept number, emp_name varchar2(10));

insert into em1 values(123,1,'we');
insert into em1 values(123,1,'asd');
insert into em1 values(123,1,'rfw');
insert into em1 values(345,2,'rtg');
insert into em1 values(345,2,'bfg');
insert into em1 values(345,2,'uyi');
commit;
```

**Query**

```
MERGE INTO em1 e
USING (
  SELECT emp_id, emp_dept, emp_name,
    row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by 1) r
  FROM em1
  WHERE emp_id in (123,345)
  ) f
ON (f.emp_id = e.emp_id and f.emp_name = e.emp_name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET e.emp_dept = case when f.r = 1 then 555 else 666 end;
```

**Result**

```
emp_id  emp_dept  emp_name
-------------------------
123     555         we
123     666         asd
123     666         rfw
345     555         rtg
345     666         bfg
345     666         uyi
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `CTE` (common table expression) adding a `ROW_NUMBER` window function `partitioned` by `emp_id` then write an `update` statement joining the `cte` and building a case statement to determine row number

The code below builds a Table Variable with Test data, selects the data to show you the "before" and then modifies with the cte method and selects the data to show you the final result.

```
 ;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
       emp_id
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY emp_SSN) AS RowNum
    FROM
       @Table
)

UPDATE t
    SET emp_dept = CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN 555 ELSE 666 END
FROM
    @Table t
    INNER JOIN cte u
    ON t.emp_id = u.emp_id
```